# Node mocha API testing with SocketIO and Express

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm working on a project where I need to serve both HTTP requests to an API and handle users communicating to each other through sockets (I'm using Socket.io for that purpose). The code of my server.js file is as follows:

```
    let initHttpServer = () => {
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(require('./routes'));
        app.get('/config.js', function(req,res) { res.write("var ROOT_URL='"+process.env.ROOT_URL+"'" + '\n'); res.end(); });
        http.listen(port, function() {
            console.log('express listening on port' + port);
            console.log('a user connected');
        });
        return app;
    }
.
.
.
conn.once('open', function() {
    initHttpServer();
});
module.exports = initHttpServer;
```

I also have a io.on('connect'...) function, but for the sake of brevity I'm not posting it here (at least yet). 
It works fine when I do tests with Postman, but I'm having trouble testing the HTTP endpoints with mocha and Chai. The code I have for testing now is the following:

```
chai.use(chaiHttp);

it('should get votes', function(done) { // <= Pass in done callback
  chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
  .get('/vote')
  .then(function(res) {
    res.should.have.status(200);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    throw err;
  });
});
```

When I run `npm test`, I get the following error:

```
  Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I've tried putting my test function inside a try/catch block as follows:

```
  it('should return all votes on /votes', function(done) {
    try{ 
      chai.request('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
      .get('/vote')
      .end(function(req,res) {
        res.should.have.status(787432189700);
        done();
      });
      --> done();
    } catch(error) {
      done(error);
    }
  });
```

If I take the done(); call I indicated with an arrow (-->), I get the aforementioned error, but if I keep it it just returns success without ever testing anything. I'm assuming that it is an asynchronous call, so done() is called before the testing finishes. Therefore, I have no clue on how to proceed. What should I do to test the API endpoints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First:

Your try/catch block will not work, you are making an async call.

### Second

Most probably is that in this line: `res.should.have.status(787432189700);` there is an error, so the **done** is not been executed.

### Try something like this:

```
let chai = require('chai')
  , chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Some test', () => {
    it('Lets see', (done) => {
        chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
            .get('/vote')
            .end(function (err, res) {    
                expect(err).to.be.null;
                expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Please observe the first parameter on the callback function is the **error**.

Comment: Oh god, can't believe I forgot to take out that line before pasting it here haha :) It was 200 before, so I don't think that was too much of an issue. However, your answer did work so thank you :)